# ArcGIS OSMLoader arcpy .encode error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, openstreetmap

I am trying to load a geofabrick .bz2 file into a file geodatabase using the OSM Simple Loader tool from http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15137
However it fails each time at this line:

**frow.setValue("Node_ID",node[0].encode("Latin-1","replace"))**
The error message is:

Runtime Error 999999: "the value type is incompatible with the field type Node_ID"

Unfortunately I am not familiar with python so am not able to attempt a fix for this error.  I am working with arc 10.2 and this was written for arc 9.2.

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this.

Here is the block of code

elif element=='/node' and hasvalidtags and ftype==0:

```
    #done with node lets load its shape
    frow = nodecursor.newrow()
    nodepnt.x=float(node[1])
    nodepnt.y=float(node[2])
    **frow.setValue("Node_ID",node[0].encode("Latin-1","replace"))**
    for f in standardFields:
        frow.setValue(f,'')
    for sTag in ftags:
        frow.setValue(sTag[0],str(sTag[1]))
    frow.SetValue('shape', nodepnt) #Load the shape
    nodecursor.insertrow(frow)
    taggednodecount+=1
    hasvalidtags=False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop using the 9.2 version and switch to using the [ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap for 10.2](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-osm-editor). I was using it for some time now and was able to process multiple OSM datasets into routable networks with no problems. There is a very detailed documentation [here](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-osm-editor/wiki/Documentation) on GitHub.

Comment: Fully agree, you should not use any tool written for 9.2 in 10.2. There have been massive changes to both ArcGIS and geodatabases from 9.2 to 10.2, as well as crucial technical changes to OpenStreetMap in the past years, like introduction of 64-bit identifiers, which render any tools 10 years old obsolete. Be aware by the way, that ESRI is working on an updated version of the 10.2 tool, suitable for 10.3 and with significantly improved multipolygon handling.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I have download the 10.2 tool however when I use the tool LOAD OSM FILE - I run into problems - Do I need a file geodatabase with 3 feature classes already set up - node,way and area_way? and all fields already created - or does the utility create them before it loads the data?  I

Comment: Please ignore the question in the previous comment -  i found instructions in https://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.locationaware.usf.edu%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2010%2F09%2FImporting-OpenStreetMap-Data-into-ArcGIS-v2.0.pps&ei=ImEQVfLzG5KV7AaA7YHQBQ&usg=AFQjCNH3cnUR7eoUT-qXJripWpZ20z0wWA&bvm=bv.88528373,d.ZGU